# Toolbar covering part of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, screen

I have a windows toolbar at the bottom of the screen and it is covering part of the screen of my website. Is there any way to make the website full screen taking in the height of the toolkit. Everything I see is hiding it.

Comment: Do you really mean Microsoft *«windows toolbar»* ? Hit [F11] if so. *«height of the toolkit»*... You mean the screen or the MS taskbar? Do you want a way for a website to "force" fullscreen mode ?

Comment: I got my answer.Thank you.